# Android ndk Fatal signal code=1

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I'm trying to call Java method from c++.

C++

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ru_sploid_platerecog_RecogActivity_FindFeatures(JNIEnv* env, jobject job, jlong addr_rgba)
{
Mat& m_rgba = *(Mat*)addr_rgba;

try
{
    const pair< string, int > fn = read_number( m_rgba, 10 );
    jclass clazz = env->FindClass("ru/sploid/platerecog/RecogActivity");
    jmethodID meth=env->GetMethodID(clazz,"onGetNumber","(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    env->CallVoidMethod(job,meth,fn.first.data());
//  cv::putText( m_rgba, fn.first.empty() ? string( "not found" ) : fn.first, cv::Point( 20, 100 ), CV_FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2.0, cv::Scalar( 255, 0, 0, 0 ) );
}
catch ( const std::exception& e )
{
    cout << "Catch exception: " << e.what() << endl;
    cv::putText( m_rgba, "Exception", cv::Point( 20, 100 ), CV_FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2.0, cv::Scalar( 255, 0, 0, 0 ) );

}
}
```

Java:

```
public void onGetNumber(String plate){
    plat=plate;
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (plat!=null)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), plat, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "((", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}
```

And app closes with
 `03-12 23:33:29.172: A/libc(21987): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x323030b9 (code=1)`

I think that I have error in C++. Thank you

Comment: Post the full stack trace, or at least more of it.

Comment: @ChrisStratton no more interesting. Only simple openCV messages

Comment: Then find and disable whatever exception handler is preventing you from getting a stack trace.  Or run under the ndk-gdb.  Or put some logging in your native code.  But leaving people to **guesss** the error location is just not reasonable.

Comment: @ChrisStratton i will do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are passing a `char*` to `CallVoidMethod()` - that's wrong, you need to pass a `jstring` object. To make a jstring around a char*, use `env->NewStringUTF()`.

In other words, the line goes like this:

```
env->CallVoidMethod(job,meth,env->NewStringUTF(fn.first.data()));
```

Assuming the string is indeed in UTF-8. If it's in another codepage (e. g. CP1251) and may contain non-ASCII characters, you need to convert.

Comment: Op, suggest you look at DeleteLocalRef too. It may be ok to leak here, but even so numbers of local references allowed are very low, 250 or so I think, so best to delete after call to java method.

Comment: It's up to 512 localrefs IIRC. Probably depends on Android version. For this snippet it doesn't matter, but if calling NewStringUTF in a loop, it makes sense to delete them.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have validation in your code. I hope this was cut out for this post. You should check that `clazz` and `method` are valid.

Anyways, if I am not missing something, you pass a `char*` to the Java method instead of jstring. You must convert `fn.first` to Java string with JNI `NewStringUTF()` or similar.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I need to use NewStringUTF()